# How do I deploy code to hardware nodes that are all on seperate networks?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, arduino, raspberry-pi

This is an interesting problem I've been thinking about recently and have not come up with or found a solution that I find acceptable.

I'm playing with Raspberry Pi's and have 6 currently that I want to use throughout a few of my personal properties for surveillance purposes.

Making them work and sending video streams to my server is all easy, well and good - but how in the world do I deploy code updates to these "nodes" that are not on the same network, some are behind wi-fi networks that I don't have port forwarding access to also, so it's not like I can just post forward and SSH into them and run some .sh magic to update things.

The best I've come up with is using autossh to keep a constant, connection open to one of my servers through reverse ssh, and then ssh in to them through my parent server in parallel and running a .sh script on them when I want to update.. But this seems overly excessive and I'm sure there's some solution or platform out there that exists to solve this - how else do companies like Redbox or Nest for example update firmware on their systems remotely?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually doing something similar. I have Pi's deployed around the city that I live in. In order to not have to worry about port-forwarding and people changing their router configurations, I started using a service called Pagekite http://pagekite.net/

I'm not affiliated with them, but I can't say enough good things about the service and price. My Pi's are hooked up to screens that need to display certain things at certain times, and I'm able to VNC in very easily no matter where the Pi is to see what's currently playing. I can obviously just ssh in as well.

The following steps from my pi setup guide deal with installing pagekite and getting it to start on boot:

19. echo deb http://pagekite.net/pk/deb/ pagekite main | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
20. sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net AED248B1C7B2CAC3
21. sudo apt-get update
22. sudo apt-get install pagekite
23. sudo leafpad /etc/pagekite.d/10_account.rc
    Replace NAME.pagekite.me with the name of the kite
    Replace YOURSECRET with whatever the secret is from the pagekite admin console
    Remove the line “abort_not_configured” and the comment above it
24. sudo cp /etc/pagekite.d/80_sshd.rc.sample /etc/pagekite.d/80_sshd.rc
25. sudo invoke-rc.d pagekite restart
26. sudo reboot

This assumes you've made an account and setup a "kite"

I think you basically need a reliable reverse tunnel such as Pagekite, especially if you plan on expanding your network, as it will turn into a nightmare at a certain size. I believe I'm just going to keep a list of ssh usernames, ssh passwords, and pagekite addresses, then write a script that loops through them and rsync's my local directory with the new code to the remote directory on the pi.

Comment: Ahh great - I thoought through this more. You can solve this issue by using GIT repositorie(s) on the PI containing the code that's ran while the device is active, and then using some .sh magic to periodically poll to see if the device should pull down updates from the production repository(s). If a new commit gets pulled down, just reboot after it's finished pulling to restart processes with updated code.

Comment: That's a great idea, I guess I needed a more complicated solution since I wanted to actually see what was on the display.